# Passing X509 value to LDAP server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap, x509

I am working on implementing spring security into my project. I need to use the username which Spring Security extracts from the certificate CN as the `uid` on the LDAP server. I am not sure of the proper way to approach this problem.  I am unsure how to pass the CN value from the x509 into the LDAP authenticator.  Anyone done this before or have any ideas?

Note: I do not need to pass the entire certificate to the LDAP server as they aren't stored there, only the username from the CN.

Edit: Here is some of the configuration in my spring security xml file:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <anonymous />
    <x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=(.*?)," /> <!-- user-service-ref needed? -->
</http>

<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="ldap://localhost:389/dc=example,dc=com" manager-dn="cn=manager,dc=example,dc=com" manager-password="myPassword" />

<authentication-manager>
    <ldap-authentication-provider
       user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=people"
       user-search-filter="(uid={0})"
       user-search-base="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
       group-search-filter="(member={0})"
       group-search-base="ou=groups"
       group-role-attribute="cn" />        
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: A CN isn't a UID. There is something seriously wrong with your problem description.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: I have a regex I am pulling part of the CN.  That part is irrelevant.  The relevant part is what I was asking, how to pass the value I pull into the LDAP server.  I have added in the tag I currently have.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [`ldap-user-service`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-ldap-user-service). Here's [an example configuration](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/itest/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ldap-provider.xml#L20) from the Spring Security test suite. Spring Security should then automatically substitute the username it extracts from the certificate CN in place of the `{0}` marker in the LDAP search filter.

The `ldap-authentication-provider` element is intended for authenticating users with a username and password, which isn't what you want with X.509, where the validation of the certificate by the container is regarded as performing the authentication.

Spring Security's X.509 authentication filter needs a `UserDetailsService` to load information for the user, so you need one in your configuration. As explained [in the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#x509) you don't need to use the `user-service-ref` attribute if there is only one, so just adding an `ldap-user-service` declaration should be sufficient.

Comment: This helped me get everything deployed.  I am having trouble with getting a user authenticated now.  There is no logging displayed, how would I enable that?  In addition, `role-prefix="none"` does not work, still throwing an attribute error on custom role.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Check any of the sample applications for how to configure logging. I don't know what you mean by "throwing an attribute error on custom role".

Comment: For example, if I put in `role-prefix="none"` under the `ldap-user-service` and use a custom role, for example `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="user" />` I get an error thrown saying `Unsupported configuration attributes: [user]`.  According to the documentation, having the role set to none, I can use my own custom roles, but this doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: If you remove the role prefix, the standard `RoleVoter` won't consume the attributes (see the FAQ). You can switch to using expressions instead `<http use-expressions='true'>` and use `access="hasRole('user')"`